# find value of attribute with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have an object:
[image]
I need to get the content of `item-id` how do I do it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import random as r
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\לימודים\\python\\selenium-project\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.get("https://www.yad2.co.il/realestate/forsale?topArea=100&area=7&city=3000")

time.sleep(5)
# find all apartments
n = r.randint(1, 10)
print(n)

time.sleep(n)

listed_bulletin_clickable_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__layout"]/div/main/div/div[4]/div[5]/div[2]/div[5]/div[@class="feeditem table"]')
print(listed_bulletin_clickable_elements)

n = r.randint(1, 10)
print(n)
time.sleep(n)

# find the item-id
item-id = listed_bulletin_clickable_elements[2].get_attribute("item-id")
print(item-id)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need some more imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t

[...]
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)
[..]
products = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@id, "feed_item_")]')))
for p in products:
    print(p.get_attribute('item-id')
```

See relevant Selenium documentation [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/).